# WCF Deserializing Problem

Tags: wcf, serialization

My "Location" object isnt getting serialized in my WCF datacontract, however, all other variables are being set properly. When I try to output a variable in the location object I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

My DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CalcRequest : BaseRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Products")]
    public List<Product> products;

    [DataMember(Name = "Location")]
    public Location location;

    [DataMember(Name = "ShippingMethod")]
    public string shippingMethod;

    [DataMember(Name = "SystemPromotionCode")]
    public string systemPromotionCode;

    [DataMember(Name = "UserPromotionCode")]
    public string userPromotionCode;
}
```

The "Location" object:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Location", Namespace = "")]
public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Country")]
    public string country;

    [DataMember(Name = "StateProvince")]
    public string stateProvince;

    [DataMember(Name = "PostalCode")]
    public string postalCode;
}
```

my XML request (version, msgtype, processorID, and customerid are in my "BaseRequest"):

```
<root>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <MsgType>type</MsgType>
    <ProcessorId>28000</ProcessorId>
    <CustomerId>28000</CustomerId>
    <Products>
        <Product>
            <SKU>1</SKU>
            <Price>2999</Price>
            <ProductName>name1</ProductName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <SKU>2</SKU>
            <Price>1999</Price>
            <ProductName>name2</ProductName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Product>
    </Products>
    <Location>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <StateProvince>OH</StateProvince>
        <PostalCode>44060</PostalCode>
    </Location>
    <ShippingMethod>USPS-NextDay</ShippingMethod>
    <SystemPromotionCode>CD1244578</SystemPromotionCode>
    <UserPromotionCode>2FDGRR</UserPromotionCode>
</root>
```

... Not sure why this isn't working... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the rest of your XML Request look like?

Comment: Updated my question with the full request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you think is missing, really....

(stuff deleted - not relevant)

**UPDATE:** to make sure the order of the elements in the XML is correct and interpreted in the right order, you might want to add `Order=xxx` statement to the data member attributes-

Otherwise, the data contract serializer will serialize (and deserialize) **in alphabetical order** (other than the XmlSerializer which serializes in the order the fields appear).

Alphabetical order is case-sensitive,i.e. any upper case characters are considered before any low-case characters.

If you have multiple elements of the same order (that's not a problem), then they'll be serialized alphabetically within their order (e.g. all elements of Order=1 will be serialized in an alphabetical fashion - then all elements with Order=2 and so on).

For derived classes, properties of base class will be serialized first(in alphabetical order) and properties of derived class later(also in alphabetical order).

Comment: I guess I was hoping someone could spot a blatant problem. When I try to Debug.WriteLine(request.location.country); it says the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: So when you look at the objects in that WriteLine function, while in debug mode, which one is null?

Comment: @marc_s  Yes, the process of converting my xml into an object seems to be the issue... but just for the Location object, since I can access all other objects

Comment: @Chris: "serializing" is typically used for object --> XML while deserializing is used for XML --> object - that's why your original question title was a bit confusing (at least to me).

Comment: Adding an "Order" fixed it. Thanks! I didn't realize it was alphabetical.